# how to remove the error class using keypress event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have added two textboxes which is CompanyName and FilePrefix so I have to make divhtml to null and clear the error message using key press event. So If the user types anything on textbox then the error message should clear.

In code behind I have used this code.

```
  divMsg.InnerHtml = "Please enter the CompanyName and FilePrefixName";
  divMsg.Attributes.Add("Class", "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible");
```

Here is my asp.net code:

```html
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="divMsg" runat="server"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputCompanyName">CompanyName</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="CompanyName"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile-Prefix">File-Prefix</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilePrefix" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="File-Prefix"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("divMsg");
});
```

Comment: use .on("input",....

Comment: try to empty the content using 
     $("#divMsg").html('');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a class "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" in backend. So, you need to remove this class on key press.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input[type='text']", function(e) {
     $(this).removeClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissible");
});
```

or else you can make html blank.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input[type='text']", function(e) {
     $("#divMsg").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
```

Is looking for a keypress *anywhere in the document* and is attempting to remove the class *from the document object itself*.  Instead, you want to do this on your `input` elements.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type=text]', function(e) {
```

This still binds a single event handler at the document level, but only affects `input type="text"` elements.  As well as refers specifically to the element with `this`.

Comment: I prefer .on("input" myself

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=text]').on('input',function (e) {
     if($('#txtCompanyName').val() !== '' && $('#txtFilePrefix').val() !== '')
     {
         $('#divMsg').text("");
     }
});
```

Because if you will remove the `#divMsg` id itself then you can not show the error back if user deletes the value from either of textboxes. So as I have shown in the code, just remove text from the div.

Comment: @Sridhar, hope this will be helpful to you.